# XML Parser gets stuck on special characters, despite encoding

Tags: c#, xml

This is the situation as it is:

I'm receiving data from an XML API. This data sometimes contains a special apostrophe character, which causes my parser to crash. This crash only occurs when I read the data from a local file. When I read the data from the stream there is no crash, but I don't get a DOM tree either: it exits without notifying me.

Below you will find a list of attempts we've made to make things work:

```
// Does not work
var web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var response = web.DownloadString("http://thetvdb.com/api/apikey/series/" + show.TVDBID + "/");
var tree = XDocument.Parse(response);

// Works
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Test\\test.xml");
var response = doc.InnerXml;
var tree = XDocument.Parse(response);

// Works
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("c:\\Test\\test.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test\\test.xml");
var tree = xmlDoc;

// Does not work
var web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
web.DownloadFile("http://thetvdb.com/api/apikey/series/" + show.TVDBID + "/", "C:\\test.xml");
var tree = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml");

// Does not work
var web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var data = web.DownloadData("http://thetvdb.com/api/apikey/series/" + show.TVDBID + "/");
var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
var tree = XDocument.Parse(response);
```

I determine whether or not something works depending on if it reaches the breakpoint in the first line of this loop:

```
if (root != null) { 
     var lastupdate = root.Element("Series").Element("lastupdated").Value;

     foreach (var epi in tree.Descendants("Episode")) {
          var season = epi.Element("SeasonNumber").Value; // Breakpoint here
     }
}
```

The crashes happen when the parser encounters this apostrophe:
[image]

When I replace this character with my own manually entered apostrophe or with `&#39`, there is no more error thrown and it continues untill the next one.
When I view the source page of the API request in firefox and chrome, it tells me the encoding is UTF-8 and code examples on the API wiki also show UTF-8 in the header.

This is where I am so far. Any ideas?

I just noticed that my result string from the API query only contains a `<Series></Series>` tag according to the XML/Text/HTML visualizer during debugging, and no `<Episode></Episode>` ones. However, when I execute the same query in my browser it shows me both. Is this possible? When I look at it trough Postman, it shows the episodes.

Update:

When I use Unicode as encoding, I don't receive any warnings and I'm able to completely parse the local xml file! I'm not an encoding expert, are there any downsides to using Unicode?

When using unicode for the stream of data, I get a bunch of asian characters.

Comment: How are you instantiating the `tree` variable?

Comment: @BenReich: I've edited my post with the code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel would be more useful if you post the XML structure/data into code tags rather than an image as people can use to make their own sample to help you.

Comment: @Prix: I have added a link to the XML code.

Comment: The XML you posted to pastebin is missing the closing `</Data>` tag.

Comment: And with the closing `</Data>` tag, the code you posted works fine for me!

Comment: Yep - I was just about to add that.  By the way, you can simply use `tree.Elements("Series")` in your for each loop.

Comment: Yes, my bad! I forgot to include the closing tag. But it there though, I just forgot to add it. It still doesn't work though: I've put a breakpoint on the first line after the foreach statement and it never pauzes. Tried both `tree.Elements("Episode")` and `tree.Descendants("Episode")`.

Comment: `tree.Descendants("Episode")` works for me

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It sounds more like something might be wrong with your debug environment.  Do other breakpoints work?

Comment: @BenReich: yes, when I put a breakpoint on the `foreach` statement, it pauzes there. And none of the code in the loop is executed, which it should. When I use the debugger to step trough it, it just skips the loop. I have noticed that there are barely any properties shown, and definitely not a result set/childelements attribute. Do you have this as well?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Can you post more of your code?  From getting the response to the first line of your foreach perhaps?  Maybe something is getting lost in the process?

Comment: @Tim: I have edited my post with the main workflow of this part of the application and also added a link to the github project. If you'd like to, you could run it (Admins tab -> Update database button) and see if your debugger pauzes as well. This would tell me if the problem lies with me or with the project.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If I understood you want to get the elements of `Episode` correct ? Then you need `foreach (XElement ep in data.Descendants("Episode").Elements())` from here you can use `ep.Name` and `ep.Value` let me know if that works for u.

Comment: @Prix: Not working either: tried it with `root.Descendants` and `tree.Descendants`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel then either the XML you are retrieving is screwed up or you missed something out I tried 4 different ways being XmlDoc, XDoc using nodes and childs and elements and they all worked just fine.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - I suggest you edit your post to reflect that the code isn't working in your environment....people don't seem to bother reading the comments and are posting answers that are not going to help you.

Comment: @Tim: good idea, I have edited my post. Right now we might be looking for a dev environment setting, even though that sounds rather farfetched to me. What could possible interfere with this?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Not sure.  A couple of easy things to try.  Close VS and then start it again.  Second, try cleaning (or rebuilding) the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: @Tim: I have restarted VS, manually emptied `bin` and `obj`, cleaned the solution and rebuilded it to no avail. Any other things I could try? (I'll remove the solution and import it again now)

Comment: Removing the solution and adding it again did not work either. I'm out of ideas. It's 4AM so I will take a break here and go to bed, hopefully someone finds the solution in the meantime. Thanks for all the help so far though!

Comment: @JeroenVannevel have you tested the XML as a file rather than downloading it ? Save the sample data you provided us with and see if you get the same result as the one you're trying to download.

Comment: @Prix: Great suggestion, please see my latest edit! I have found the error

Comment: I've removed the auto-wiki from your question as your edits are legitimate for the most part. Please take care not to make too many separate small edits to your question - the auto-wiki feature is there as a safeguard for users who may be bumping their questions to gain rep, which I trust you're not doing here. In case this happens again you can always flag your post for a moderator to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the encoding of your data. This allows you to get raw binary (so no problems with encoding).

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
byte[] data = myWebClient.DownloadData(uri);

string xmlContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

**EDIT** Following your most recent developments with Unicode I would say that the data is actually encoded in UTF-16. Unicode is not an encoding type, it's essentially just a coded character set - i.e. a set of characters and a mapping between the characters and integer code points representing them. When you "encode something in Unicode" it usually means UTF-16. Anyway, glad that your problem is solved!

Comment: Like what? The XML is an API response, I don't have control over it. When I use the local file and add this line at the top `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` it still doesn't work.

Comment: utf-8 is not the encoding then, open the XML with your browser and go to "View" on the menu and then go to "Text Encoding" or "Character Encoding" and see what is ticked. Meanwhile, if that doesn't work try replacing the accent with &#39; and see if it works.

Comment: Where exactly do I check the text encoding? I've used `view source` and it shows the encoding I typed above. I have followed your suggestion and the replacing works: the error is thrown at the next character in line. I have opened the xml file with n++, set the encoding to UTF-8 and it shows encoding errors (`x92`) everywhere a faulty accent is supposed to be.

Comment: Tha's because the API is not encoding the file in utf-8 and most parsers use utf-8 by default if no encoding is specified (which is your case). Ideally it would be nice for you to find out what is the encoding used by the API so that you can add it to the top of the file. My suggestion is: Without adding the line at the top, open the XML with your browser. Browsers usually try to infer the encoding based on what they see, so go to the "View" menu on the top, go to the option Text Encoding and you should see what encoding does your browser think that is, then add that encoding to the file.

Comment: I can't find where chrome shows that, but in firefox I've found it's UTF-8 encoding, which is the same as I've already tried. I'll try to contact the API maintainer and see what they say.

Comment: It looks like you're using C#, can you try parsing the document using this: var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(
                 File.ReadAllText("filelocation", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)); to see what you get? The XDocument is in  XDocument class is part of the System.Xml.Linq namespace.

Comment: I'm receving a `URI is too long` error when I use this code:

`var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(File.ReadAllText("c:\\Test\\test.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)); var tree = xmlDoc;`

Any experience with it? I'm googling around, but so far I don't see why this is returning an error.

Comment: Sorry. Use XDocument.LoadXml instead of  XDocument.Load. It should work.

Comment: Are you sure? According to the documentation there is no such method and intellisense doesn't offer any either.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Comment: You might have solved it! I used `XDocument.Parse()` instead and now I'm hitting the breakpoint inside the loop. I'm looking for a way to specify the encoding in the stream now.

Comment: Nice! What if you try something like var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml"); and see what happens (both using the line at the top of the file and not using it). If it works you might not need to specify the encoding or you might just need to add the line on the top of the file.

Comment: Using `var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test\\test.xml");` works both with and without the encoding specified at the top of the file! However I've tried it with the stream by setting the encoding to UTF8 (`web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`) but this didn't make a difference. Should I set the encoding differently?

Comment: Did you do
var web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string s = webClient.DownloadString()

By this order?

Comment: I've tried downloading it to a file and then reading it, but this didn't work. I have edited my post to include the code from this attempt. Yes, I did it in that order.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. I have added my code to the OP to reflect the changes I've made. This is the way you intended, right? When adding `web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` after the webclient instantiation, it's still not working.

Comment: That is really weird, just to confirm, did you add the web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 before the download string?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll add it to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var tree = XElement.Parse(response);
foreach(var epi in tree.Descendants("Episode"))
{
   ...
}
```

If Data is your root node and there are no buried Episode's, then you can replace Descendants with Elements.

Comment: `Descendants` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` collection - how is converting that to a generic list going to help?  It's an unnecessary step.

Comment: @Tim it depends on what OP is doing in the loop, such as deleting elements.

Comment: I've tried it, but it made no difference. The code of the loop can be found in edit 4 in the OP. All it does is retrieve values, create an anonymous object and call the repository with this. Only read actions on the DOM.

Comment: @Tim Also, if he is setting a breakpoint, without the .ToList() it probably never gets executed because of the delayed execution of Enumerables.

Comment: @ChuckSavage - I was able to get the breakpoint to work without the .ToList().  I would expect the for each loop to enumerate the enumerable, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Tim Of course, but if you delete elements of the loop within the loop, then the loop will have unpredictable results.  I'm not going to tailor my answer to just his needs, because answers are supposed to help multiple people that will look at this post in the future.  The `ToList` is `to-be-safe` code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I tested your XML with my code, it works perfectly.  I have to conclude that there are no `Episode`s in your running XML.

Answer (score 0):

`&#39` is an html escape for certain browsers.  Use `&apos;` instead, it is the correct xml escape sequence.

It looks likely that you got "smart quoted" by one of those annoying microsoft products that changes all your quotes and apostrophes to curly ones that claim to be in ISO-8859-1/Latin-1, but are really Win-1252 with a missing C0 plane.  If that is the case, only a Win-1252 is encoding is going to parse that document for you.  Or you can switch out the curly apos for a regular one and all will be ok.

Comment: I'm receiving the data in this manner from an API. How would you suggest I use `'`? I guess I could replace every faulty apostrophe by a normal one, but how would I find the charactercode of this apostrophe in the first place? Isn't this very vulnerable for other special characters then?

Comment: This has actually been a huge problem for me with enterprise users editing their xml in MS Word and saving it, assuming all will be ok.  I ended up preprocessing all the xml files and checking for the curly quotes and apostrophes, I'm sure someone else has a better way, but that was the hack I did.

Comment: If I'd use the replace method, what should I use as first argument for `response.Replace()`? Do you happen to know the code of this character?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution and it's somewhat anticlimatic. The episodes weren't retrieved because my API string was incomplete: it was supposed to end with `/all/`, but I must have forgotten it somewhere and copied from that point forward. It was the last place I was looking.

By changing the API call I could now retrieve all episodes.
There are no more encoding errors (even though I changed nothing to that) and right now it has already retrieved 4000 episodes, so I'm assuming the rest will go without issues as well.

Someone made this a community wiki: I'm not sure if that status is still warranted, seeing as this was a localized issue. I've learned a lot about XML/APIs from these conversations though, thanks to everyone involved!